# How do I upload files to a Github repository?

Tags: github

I am using the Github wesite
and I want to upload my code to it.
Is there a way to do this in the GUI, like a Chrome extension or something?
Or is it required that I use git to do it? If git is required, how do I use it to upload a Python script to my existing Github repo?

Comment: What problem are you having exactly? And it shouldn't matter if you're on Windows or Mac or Linux, pushing a repo to any Git repo is going to be the same.

Comment: you first need to stage your files using "git add", then you will need to commit your changes using the command "git commit", and finally you will be able to upload your changes using the command "git push".

Comment: You use the command line, Terminal/cmd, etc..

Answer (score 1):

`init` a repository, `commit` your work and `push` it to the remote repository.

Comment: Is there a way to do this from the website??

Comment: I am using [Git Extension](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions/) for publishing my work to GitHub on Windows, just because I like GUIs.

Comment: Ok. Is this a browser extension? If so, what browser? Chrome of Firefox?

Comment: No, it is GUI for [git](https://git-scm.com/). If you want to edit your files directly in GitHub repository, go to your repository at https://github.com/UserName/RepositoryName, browse to the file you want to edit or create a new one and do your derired edits. When you are complete, type in commit message and press `Commit new file`/`Commit changes`

Comment: Ok. Is there a `Linux` version?

Comment: Most of linux users I know use command line commands to manage and work with repositories like `git commit` and `git push`. Maybe you should specify what do you want to do on more than 3 lines.